# Force.com IDE: I want "work offline" to be default

Tags: deployment, ide, force.com-ide

Every time I switch the source for my project (between sandboxes or between production and a sandbox) it defaults to "Work Online", and I need to remember to switch that or else it starts deploying things willy nilly.

I'm using version control, so I want to be in control of what's on the server and what's not. I think I may have accidentally saved something to my production org because I didn't remember to uncheck that (there's a deployment with a random hash name that says I deployed it).

### Is there a way to make it default to working offline?

Comment: You should have a separate project for each org. Changing the source for a specific project is a bad idea.

Comment: @AdrianLarson wait, really? How do you handle version control if you use a different project for each feature, dev, staging, and prod?

Comment: Each org should also be a separate repo. Not per feature, per instance.

Comment: So your production org should be a separate repo from the sandbox where you test things for production?

Comment: Yes absolutely. See my answer below. I will be clearing these comments out shortly since they are reflected in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way we typically manage this flow as consultants (at least in my experience) is to have one repository/project per org. You should never change the source org for any of your projects locally.

When using the Force.com IDE to manage multiple instances, I use a naming convention that indicates production/sandbox, client, and sandbox name. What that looks like for me is something like:

- Production - MyClient1
- Production - MyClient2
- Sandbox - MyClient1 (adrian)
- Sandbox - MyClient1 (dev)
- Sandbox - MyClient1 (staging)
- Sandbox - MyClient2 (asdf)
- Sandbox - MyClient2 (staging)

Your version control will then have a detailed view of your development flow. You will see very granular changes in `dev`, then hopefully some bigger chunks and some reactive in `staging`, and ideally only complete feature deployments in each commit to your `production` repository.

Comment: So to get changes from `dev` to `staging`, you merge from the one repo into the other?

Comment: Yeah that's definitely the direction DX is headed. For us it was usually a cycle of deploy -> pull down locally -> commit. You don't need it to be source driven for this model to work, it just lessens friction.